# Navigating to different views without reloading entire page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I have a layout page that has one dropdown box. I created 3 views that will make use of this
layout. The value selected in the dropdown will be used in all 3 views created. 
I have actionlinks used for navigation in the layout. Here is what I will like to achieve

1. Avoid reloading the entire page(layout) when I navigate from view to view since I want to keep
   the dropdown value selected.

How can I achieve this such that it is only the content of the views that will be changing
when I navigate from page to page by clicking on the action links. The value of dropdown selected
must always remain the same unless changed by user

```
        @model Company.Domain.Classes.Companyviewmodel
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
            <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="page">

                @{
                    ViewBag.Title = "Project Status Maintenance";
                }

                <div id="MainContent1">

                    <div id="ProjID">
                        <label for="SelectProjID">Project:</label>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlprojects", Model.GetProjectInformationActive.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.GetProjectInformationActive.SelectedProject)                     
                    </div>            
                    <ul>              
                        <li class="pp1">@Html.ActionLink("Section1", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li class="pp2">@Html.ActionLink("Section2", "GetSection1Data", "Home")</li>
                        <li class="pp3">@Html.ActionLink("Section3", "GetSection2Data", "Home")</li>                
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="divide" />
                    @RenderBody()

                </div>     
                <footer>
                    <div class="ftrcontent">
                        <p>Got it !!</p>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>   

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to do partial page loads. To start, give a css class to your links so that we can use those as our jQuery selectors when wiring up the ajax behavior.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Section1", "Index", "Home",null, new {@class="ajaxLink"})
@Html.ActionLink("Section2", "GetSection1Data", "Home", new {@class="ajaxLink"})
@Html.ActionLink("Section3", "GetSectionwData", "Home", new {@class="ajaxLink"})
```

Now you should have a container div in your page to which we will load the partial view content. May be your current view (index ?) , you can add a container view like this

```
<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

Now, let's listen to the `click` event on our links, get the content of the target page's via ajax and load to the container div. Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your page, we can use jQuery `load()` method.

```
$(function(){

   //Load the first link's content on document ready
   var firstLinkHref=$("a.ajaxLink").eq(0).attr("href");
   $("#pageContent").load(firstLinkHref);

   $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
   });

});
```

Since we are loading partial page content to our placeholder div, we do not need to return the full markup(including layout) from your action methods, We just need to the partial view content. You may use the `PartialView()` method instead of `View()` method to achieve this.

```
public ActionResult GetSection1Data()
{
  if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    return PartialView();
  }
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this. So is this <div id="pageContent"></div> reusable for all 3 pages ?

Comment: That should be just in your initial page (where you have the links). It is more like a place holder to other page content will be loaded.

Comment: I have the links in my master page. Are you saying this will be in my master page? Which section do I put that?

Comment: in your current page (Index i guess)

Comment: So this section will be the container for holding the content of other pages?

Comment: Again, how will the jquery be smart enough to know the link that was clicked since they all have the same class name?

Comment: Last question sorry. Is the load event like document.ready? Is this what you are referring to? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It is reading the href attribute value of the clicked link and using that to load method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111958/discussion-between-user2320476-and-shyju).

Comment: Just a quick feed back about this. It works good but the landing page is the problem. The content does not show until I click link one for the index page.

Comment: I guess the main question now is how do I load a partial view on page load of a mvc application. If I know this, the problem will be solved. The index pages loads at the moment but not using the layout page.

Comment: In the document ready event, trigger the click of the first link.

Comment: Do you have a sample code please? I am completely new to this. I can create a document.ready function

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it right away and will get back to you in 5mins. Appreciate all your help

Comment: It works like magic. You are the best. Thanks for your help. This has been a big problem but now resolved.