# Keep the model updated asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET website that loads a list of people in multiple pages, in order to navigate, i had to query a limited number of people each time the user move to the next or the previous page, so in each query, the controller needs to know in what page we already are, the problem with the concept of an ASP.NET website, is that in each page, the controller start fresh from the beginning and the data like the page number or any other data is lost.

Is there any way to keep the model updated between each query in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Are you using Gridview?

Comment: No, for the view simple html css

Comment: Use ajax to partial page load 

Follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228155/navigating-to-different-views-without-reloading-entire-page

Comment: You can pass the variables that you need to know in the backend as GET parameters or POST data.